# Gradle experimental build.gradle configuration

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

[image]

I'm currently using Android experimental gradle plugin. I need to have multiple custom sub folder in res but when I combine with main java source srcDirs, it will always prompt error message

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe''
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

my gradle version is 2.5

What is the proper way to configure android.sources for experimental gradle version

in my app's **build.gradle** file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
 ...
 android.sources {

    main {

        java {
            source {
                srcDirs = ["src"]
            }

        }

        res{

            source {
                srcDirs = [ 'src/main/res/property/search',
                            'src/main/res/property',
                            'src/main/res/agent',
                            'src/main/res'
                ]
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current latest and standard configuration which i uses for build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.0.0.jar')
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.4.0'





}
```

Comment: your gradle is different from mine. Mine has a "model" wrapped as outer layer from "android" and my apply plug in is "apply plugin: com.android.model.application"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add **model** tag before android, like it

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
...
model.android.sources {

    main {

        java {
            source {
                srcDir = 'src'
            }

        }

        res {

            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/res/property/search',
                           'src/main/res/property',
                           'src/main/res/agent',
                           'src/main/res'
                ]
            }

        }
    }
}
```